# C++ std::function operator=

Tags: c++, c++11, stdmap, std-function, stdbind

I am unable to compile a simple program in C++11.
You can have a look at it here http://cpp.sh/9muxf.

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>
#include <tuple>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

typedef int Json;
typedef string String;

class Integer/*: public PluginHelper*/
{
public:
    Json display(const Json& in)
    {
        cout << "bad" << endl;
        return Json();
    }

    map<String, function<Json(Json)>>* getSymbolMap()
    {
        static map<String, function<Json(Json)>> x;
        auto f = bind(&Integer::display, this);
        x["display"] = f;
        return nullptr;
    }
};
```

The issue is coming at line `x["display"] = f;`

You be of great help if you make me understand what is happening here :).
Can `std::function` not be copied?

Comment: Did the compiler perchance emit an error message?

Comment: Some people think bind is now useless since there's lambdas/closures, so consider `auto f = [this](Json j)->Json{return display(j);};` as an alternative

Comment: you need `#include <string>`

Comment: I don't know why but it compiles here `http://cpp.sh/7w6c`

Comment: @Mayank It might be included by other stl header files, such as `iostream`. But it's not guaranteed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem lies here:

```
auto f = bind(&Integer::display, this);
```

`Integer::display` takes `Json const&` and you bind it with no explicit arguments. My gcc rejects such a bind expression, but both cpp.sh's compiler and my clang let this compile, possibly incorrectly because the language standard states that:

> `*INVOKE* (fd, w1, w2, ..., wN)` [func.require] shall be a valid
>   expression for some values *w1, w2, ..., wN*, where 
>   `N == sizeof...(bound_args)`

You can fix your problem by making your bound function object `f` proper - just add a placeholder for the `Json` argument:

```
auto f = bind(&Integer::display, this, placeholders::_1);
```

[demo](http://cpp.sh/577l5)

Answer (score 2):

`Integer::display()` takes one parameter. You should specify it as the placeholder, otherwise the signature of functor generated from [std::bind](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) will be regarded as taking nothing, which doesn't match the signature of `function<Json(Json)>`.

```
auto f = bind(&Integer::display, this, std::placeholders::_1);
//                                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
x["display"] = f;
```

[LIVE](http://cpp.sh/6tl3l)